# nexus maven artifacts disappear from repository

Tags: maven, nexus, artifacts

Some of my nexus maven artifacts disappear from repository after 1-5 days. Cannot reproduce that yet.

How can that happen?

Maven settings.xml:

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*,!codehaus.snapshots,!snapshots</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.2.252:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <mirrorOf>codehaus.snapshots,snapshots</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.2.252:8080/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Artifacts downloaded from public and public snapshots groups.

Comment: do you have configured any scheduled tasks in nexus? To repair or re-index the repositories?

Comment: No. Scheduled tasks tab empty if viewed by anonymous user and security is disabled, anonymous is admin.

Comment: are these artifacts snapshots? do they disappear from nexus only or also from the file system?

Comment: Yes. These artifactes are snapshots, and Snapshots are in public repositories group. Posting settings.xml

Comment: I cannot reproduce now, but i think from filesystem too.

Comment: Do you have the repo setup to delete artifacts once they're released?

Answer (score 2):

Snapshot releases in public repositories are most likely being purged. You'll have no control over this.

snapshot revisions are designed to be temporary in nature.